# How to retrieve data from JSON file without manually entering the data mapbox

Tags: javascript, json, coordinates, mapbox-gl-js

I want to use a JSON file containing coordinates to plot points on a map with Mapbox and add markers at those locations. I've followed a few of their [tutorials](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/custom-markers-gl-js/) and searched elsewhere (stack overflow, Github etc) to see if I could find a solution but nothing seemed to work. I'm not getting any errors when I open the HTML file in the browser but the markers aren't appearing on the map at the JSON's coordinates and I'm not really sure how to get the JSON's coordinates to be read and then plotted on the [map](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/show-changes-over-time/). I want the JSON to be used from the same folder as the project and not a [URL](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/external-geojson/) so this didn't work for me either.

```
<script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam1hcHNkamFuZ28iLCJhIjoiY2tydzIwazc4MGNnODJvb2VhNHNhZDd5diJ9.iwGIdgMHrcjbNu1xJRAElQ';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  // style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-0.19346, 51.50405],
  zoom: 9
});

map.on('load', () => {
  map.addLayer({
    id: 'restaurants',
    type: 'Point',
    source: {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: './restaurants.json' // replace this with the url of your own geojson
    },
    paint: {
      'circle-radius': [
        'interpolate',
        ['linear'],
        ['number', ['get', 'coordinates']],
        0,
        4,
        5,
        24
      ],
      'circle-color': [
        'interpolate',
        ['linear'],
        ['number', ['get', 'coordinates']],
        0,

        1,

        2,

        3,

        4,

        5,

      ],
      'circle-opacity': 0.8
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your only error, but this line:

> `type: 'Point',`

should be:

> `type: 'circle',`

Comment: I assumed that the type should have matched my json file as keeping it as circle didn't load the data onto the map.

Comment: The layer definition, including type, has to match the style spec: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/ There are lots of reasons why data may not appear on a map.

Comment: I'm not seeing where I might be deviating from the style spec though. I only have the code that I shared above thanks to the tutorials on Mapbox.

Comment: As I said, the `type` field has to match one of the `type` values for a layer. Such as `circle`. Whereas `Point` is not such a value.